# How to Change Grid subdivisions (2.81)

Tags: 3d-view

The subdivisions options in viewport overlays is greyed out in 2.81. Any changes in this have no effect on grid display. Maybe, I have set some system option by mistake. How do I enable grid subdivisions in 2.81?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). It seems this option is temporarily disabled in 2.81 to keep the units coherent across the UI. Hopefully, in 2.82 it will work again.

Comment: @JachymMichal Thank you very much for the update :)

Answer (score 5):

Go to *Scene Properties> Units> Unit System* and set *Metric* or *Imperial* to *None*.

Then the option to change the subdivisions in the *Viewport Overlays* will be enabled again.

I'm using Blender v2.82.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I found when I set units system to none the grid subdivision worked.